# Stack Overflow for Teams, can teams be merged?

Tags: support, merge-accounts, stack-overflow-for-teams

If multiple individuals create their own individual Teams, can they later be consolidated/merged under 1 unified Team (Team Name, URL, membership, etc.) with content from both teams preserved?

Comment: We'll need to revisit that, but for now, teams is still a SO feature, and I'll be migrating this to MSO. I will be posting a meta post asking about that shortly with recent changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, sorry, Stack Overflow for Teams cannot be merged. Content would have to be migrated by hand. If you are on the Business plan, some content could be migrated via the write API.